# Compile Linux perf with ncurses interface?

Tags: linux, compilation, ncurses, perf

If I use distro provided Linux perf binary, it usually has a nice ncurses interface (i.e. perf top).

However, when I compile perf from linux kernel source, it only contains text based output.
[image: perf without ncurses interface]

I wonder what do I need to do to compile it with ncurses support?
P.S. I have libncurses5-dev:amd64 installed.

Comment: When compiling, look at the output of `./configure --help` (or similar). It'll probably have an option similar to `--with-ncurses`.

Comment: Unfortunately, with Linux perf, there is no configure.

Comment: I read the log and it was missing libslang2-dev ... I will probably close this question as it's trivial when people review the log :(

Comment: Nice find, @patrick, sorry for the line noise.

Comment: For the record, the information about present or missing libraries is displayed at the top of the logs (but it is easy to miss since compilation logs fill the screen after that). Scroll up, or re-run `make` to obtain just the relevant part about libraries. @Patrick: thanks, I had skipped the logs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perf` uses no `./configure` script as it is part of user-space tools built with linux kernel (and kernel has not autotools nor configure). There are makefiles in perf subdirectory [`tools/perf`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/?v=4.8) in linux kernel tree, and you can rerun make in it.

Two extra user interfaces, TUI and GTK are disabled in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/Makefile.config?v=4.8#L499. TUI is disabled when there is no newt/slang (`/usr/include/slang/slang.h` or `/usr/include/slang.h`) and GTK2 UI needs [gtk2-devel or libgtk2.0-dev](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/Makefile.config?v=4.8#L516). Feature macro are defined in [`Makefile.perf`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/Makefile.perf?v=4.8):

```
 42 # Define NO_SLANG if you do not want TUI support.
 43 #
 44 # Define NO_GTK2 if you do not want GTK+ GUI support.
```